# How can I pass the output from groovy script to the soap request

Tags: soapui, groovyscriptengine

I am new to SoapUI and writing groovy scripts. In my request parameters, I have two fields "from and to". from is the current date and to is one year later date. so I have written a groovy script to add one year to the current date. and the same output I am passing to the request. Please help me in correcting the mistake.

I want the one year later date in "to" parameter of the request.
Please elaborate as I am new to groovy and soapUI. I have gone through several answers. Thank you.

```
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory)
{
def addYear = new Date() + 367.days
log.info addYear.format("yyyy-MM-dd") 
}
```

`And this is my request in SoapUI:` 
    `from  : ${TestSuite#bt} (Its a senML request)`
    `to : ${#TestCase#addYear}`

Comment: Is this resolved ? or are you still on the lookout for answers ?

Comment: Since you can add a script basically anywhere in SoapUI (Project/TestSuite/TestCase setup/teardown, test case step, test step assertion), can you specify where exactly are you trying to run that script?
Regarding the property expansions, you can find more info on the soapui [documentation page:](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a groovy step script, you can do it like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["YourApiRequestStep"]

def Response = testStep.getProperty("response").value;

def someFieldYouWantToSave = ""


if (Response == null) {
    log.error('No Response found.');
}
else {
    def jSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
    def json = jSlurper.parseText(Response);
    if (json.get("theFieldFromTheResponse") == null){
        log.error "TheFieldFromTheResponse not found in response. Please execute the teststep and try again"
    } else {
        someFieldYouWantToSave = json.get("theFieldFromTheResponse").toString()

        // YOUR LOGIC HERE FOR MODIFYING THE "someFieldYouWantToSave" value

        //SAVE THE FIELD
        testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("someFieldYouWantToSave", someFieldYouWantToSave)
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you can always see what context variables you can use by looking in the upper - right location of the script window. For example, if you're using a Groovy Script step, the variables are: **log**, **context** and **testRunner**. If you try to use the above example somewhere else, like in the test case assertion script, it won't work since that one is invoked with **log**, **context** and **messageExchange**. You can find out how to grab the values from various places in your project by taking a look at the examples [from the documentation](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion.html)

With these 3 pieces of information, you should be able to achieve your goal, regardless of the place you're using it.